# Pumping Lemma Confusing

Tags: automata

Note: $\lambda $ means empty in this case.

[image]

If $v\neq\lambda$, then $|v|\ge1$. But then, the 2nd condition allows $uv^0w$ where $v^0=\lambda$ and $|v|=0$???

Shouldn't the 2nd condition only allow $i\ge1$ to maintain the 1st condition?

Comment: $|v|\geq 1$ and $|v^0|=0$ because $v^0=\lambda$. Where is the contradiction? At no point can you deduce that $|v|=0$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek  How can we have $|v| \ge1$ when we have an instance of $uv^0w$, so $v = v^0$, $|v^0|=0$  (pumping $0$ times)?

Answer (score 1):

$v^0 = \lambda$ says absolutely nothing about the length of $v$. It is true for all words by definition (the concatenation of zero copies of $v$ is always empty).

$v\not = \lambda$ is a condition for selecting a factor $v$. It does not carry over to possible powers of $v$, which are in general different from $v$. For natural numbers, the fact that $5^0 =1$ does not make $5\not= 1$ untrue either.